# Calling Console application from web

Tags: vb.net, console-application

can we call and pass argument to a console application from web application?

for example I have a web application have 3 textbox.the first and second textbox having value 10 and 20 and the 3rd text box for the value return from the console application.

the console application for adding this two values and return the result.

how can I achieve by vb.net code any one help?

Comment: You can, but why?  There's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do than to call a console app from a web page.

Comment: @Tim  how??

Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Arun\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\bin\Debug");

is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Process` class to get the process started and read the output to fill the third textbox value:

```
Dim proc = New Process() With { _
        .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo() With { _
        .FileName = "program.exe", _
        .Arguments = "your command line arguments if needed", _
        .UseShellExecute = False, _
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True, _
        .CreateNoWindow = True _
        } _
   }

   proc.Start()

   'After process starts, you read the output

   While Not proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream
       ' do something with line (append a stringbuilder for example)
       Dim line As String = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()
   End While
```

Comment: Error 1 Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'.

Comment: Corrected ;). Using with doesn't need the use of key clause.

Comment: How can  we pass multiple arguments..here I need Textbox value and textbox 2 value.

Comment: In the .arguments string. Just use .Arguments = Textbox1.Text & " " & Textbox2.Text

Comment: Thanks...And after  proc.Start() I just try    proc.WaitForExit()        Response.Write(proc.ExitCode.ToString())..   is it possible...  but the problem is in console application how can we return the value.

Comment: Public Sub Main(ByVal sArgs() As String)
        If sArgs.Length = 0 Then                
            Console.WriteLine("no arguments passed->")
        Else                                    
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim j As Integer
            Dim s As Integer

            i = sArgs(0)
            j = sArgs(1)
            s = i + j

        End If


    End Sub



This is my coinsole pgm.here how can I return S

Comment: Just do Console.Writeline(value); of the resultant value :)

Comment: proc.Start()
        While Not proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()
        MsgBox(line)
        End While
..
I tried this code ..but the msgbox showing the textbox1 and textbox 2 values only

Comment: So you can't do this from a SPA application? You must use .net features?